# How to configure IP tables to only allow ports 25 and 80

Tags: port, block, iptables

Hello I want to allow only ports 25 and 80 and all other ports to be closed.
I tried to configure my Ubuntu linux, but I dropped all the ports...

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 5):

You want "--dport", not "--sport", if you want to accept connections directed to port 25 or port 80.

Comment: Agreed. How you have it set now is telling it to only allow packets in to the server if the computer they came from sent the packets out ports 25 or 80, which is practically never. The packet itself will have a source port of a random high number and a destination port (i.e. your server) of 80 or 25. So the rule should say --dport

Comment: I tried replacing -sport with dport and the result is that I have no internet access -> 80 port is blocked....

Comment: I tried replacing -sport with dport and the result is that I have no internet access -> 80 port is blocked....
I haven't hacked port 25, because I do not know how exactly but the idea is that the suggestion is not working. So the question is still open

Comment: Can you do "iptables -L -n" so we can see what your configuration looks like?

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@ubuntu:~#

Comment: It would be nicer if the output were formatted better, but what you have essentially looks correct.  You do have a web server and mail server up and running, listening on ports 25 and 80, right?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting but I can not make it better. I do not have 80 port running... I do not know how to test port 25, but it seems that everything is blocked. I restarted the system to have access to http....

Comment: If you have no services listening on those ports, it really doesn't matter if the firewall is configured correctly.  Please do that first.  You can use "telnet" to test TCP connectivity.  You can google on how to do that.

Comment: I tried telnet and it can not make connection.... this is my new IP tables configuration iptables -t filter -F
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,80,81,110,443,465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT  -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -S
It seems that it is working ... but again telnet to the open ports can not be established... Do you have an idea why or to propose other way to test it?